# Selecting entries by date - >= NOW(), MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, date

I have a Calendar of Events table and I would like to select events with dates equal to or greater than today. When I use the following SELECT statement, it only retrieves events in the future (> NOW()):

```
<?php    
$db->query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date >= NOW()");
?>
```

How would I go about selecting all events that are either today or in the future?

Thank you

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You are looking for [`CURDATE()`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp):

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date >= CURDATE()");
```

Or:

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date >= CURRENT_DATE()");
```

Comment: Good answer but its just check time and no date!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM events  WHERE event_date >= NOW()`

Comment: What is the difference of CURDATE and NOW?

Comment: The difference is that `NOW()` also includes time information. But you may actually need to use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` instead of `NOW()` and `CURDATE()`.

Answer (score 20):

The reason that this query:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date >= NOW()
```

...returns records from the future, is because NOW() includes the time as well as the date.  And that time portion indicates the time at which the [function or triggering] statement began to execute.  So that means the start of the day in a DATETIME data type looks like: `2010-06-24 00:00:00` (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, to microsecond precision), which NOW() would show something like `2010-06-24 14:24:31`...

Here are your options:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date >= DATE(NOW())
SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date >= DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date >= CURRENT_DATE()
SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date >= CURRDATE()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do

```
<?php    
$db->query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(event_date) >=     UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())");
?>
```

Which is more accurate than using CURTIME() if by any chance your using time as well as date

Answer (score 1):

If you care only about the date, not the time, use [CURDATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) instead of `NOW()`.

Of course you can alternatively use the synonym `CURRENT_DATE` (with or without parentheses after it), but the docs I pointed to give `CURDATE` as the first spelling;-).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that now() is very accurate.  So dates for today and before now because they started at the beginning of the day.

Use this:

```
select * from events where datediff(event_date, now()) >= 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the difference between CURDATE and NOW:

```
mysql> select CURDATE();
+------------+
| CURDATE()  |
+------------+
| 2017-03-17 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2017-03-17 09:04:45 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I always use NOW just to be accurate