# SQL statement for starting date and over

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use my query to find data which are only equal to today and future? Which mean any data with date that pass today, will not shown. I have this query, but my syntax might be wrong. Please assist me:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM kiosk_directory.tbldetails where start_date='" & today & "' andalso start_date!<='" & today & "';"
```

I want data which equal today and data that not less than today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM kiosk_directory.tbldetails where start_date >= Cast(Now() As Date)
```

Or any Date in accepted MySql Formats I usually go with 'YYYY-MM-DD' cause for whatever reason I don't mix up the days/months (I grew up learning both MM-DD and DD-MM).

```
SELECT * FROM kiosk_directory.tbldetails where start_date >= Cast('2014-7-1' As Date)
```

Though you don't need the cast then...

```
    SELECT * FROM kiosk_directory.tbldetails where start_date >= '2014-7-1'
```

Comment: 1 quick question. I set my start_date as Date which it should be a date without time. But when I grad from my code,my datareader read the start_date with default 12:00:00 AM so it will be 2014-07-04 12:00:00 AM. Why is this happen? How to make the column is just date only?

Comment: I'm not sure what language or library you are using to read the SQL results, but casting to a date so "Select Cast(start_date as Date)" usually resolves it

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said which RDBMS you're using, but this would be the query in mysql:
`SELECT * FROM kiosk_directory.tbldetails where TO_DAYS(start_date) >= TO_DAYS(NOW())`

I'm using TO_DAYS assuming start_date is a timestamp. If it only contains dates without a time component, then it's not necessary to use TO_DAYS()

Answer (score 0):

As per [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114769/selecting-entries-by-date-now-mysql)

```
"SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date >= CURRENT_DATE()";
```