# how to compare a given date with current date in sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql

i want to write a query to compare a given date with today date with timestamp.
given date can be the today date, if the date is same it will compare the time.

```
select * from abcTable where submitDate <= now();
```

here its comparing only the date not the time.

`submitDate` is anydate which is in the db table.

Comment: what's the datatype of `orderDeliveredDate`?

Comment: And which time zone do you want to take "today" in?

Comment: @JonSkeet ofcourse it will take the server timezone. Which is gmt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL compare now() (only date, not time) with a datetime field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533914/mysql-compare-now-only-date-not-time-with-a-datetime-field)

Comment: @akash What is the datatype of submitDate

Comment: Possible duplicate, there are many existing discussions for similar questions. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114769/selecting-entries-by-date-now-mysql)

Comment: Further to @vkp's comment, it seems that your `orderDeliveredDate` is only a date, not a datetime or a timestamp. Also, in this crazy world of globalization, `sysdate()` would be a better choice than `now()`.

Comment: I wouldn't take any time decision as an "of course" (and it's not clear whether by "GMT" you actually mean "UTC" or "Europe/London time"...)

Comment: @RanaGhosh Date

Comment: @M.Rizzo Indeed its Impossible duplicate of the link you refereed.

Comment: @RohitGulati Atleast read the question first. Even the code which is have pasted is comparing the date with current date. I want something which can compare the time if the date is same.

Comment: Have you tried all these options : [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3114818/5803493). It says now compares the time. @Akash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have specified that column submitDate is of datatype Date while, as per your question its datatype should be Timestamp.When the datatype of submitDate column is Date, there is no reason to even compare the time.

However if you need to still want to compare the submitDate with current timestamp, you can do it this way:
**select * from submitDate where date_format(submitDate,'%d/%m/%y %T') <= now();**

**Edit: The above query is for Mysql**

Comment: Thanks, Its exactly what i was looking for. But here if you are comparing the date with time you also give the now time with seprated time format > select * from submitDate where date_format(submitDate,'%d/%m/%y %T') <= date_format(now(),'%d/%m/%y %T') ;

Comment: Glad to know that your issue was sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

```
GETDATE() --2017-01-17 08:19:28.403
```

you can get day, month and year separately by doing:

```
select DAY(getdate())  --17
select month(getdate())  --1
select year(getdate()) --2017
```

if you are on sql server 2008, there is the DATE date time which has only the date part, not the time:

```
select cast (GETDATE() as DATE) --2017-01-17
```

OR you you can try:

```
select * from abcTable where submitDate <= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE);
```

OR

```
select * from abcTable where submitDate <= cast((now()) as date);
```